# Twitter API request works using Postman, but not fetch

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

I am going through the OAuth process and am on the very last step where I call the access_token endpoint

```
let twitterUrl = `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_token=${oauth_token}&oauth_verifier=${oauth_verifier}`;
```

When I do this request using fetch I get 401 error

```
fetch(twitterUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  mode:"no-cors",
}) 
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

When I do the exact request using postman it work just fine.

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I am thinking I will take this out of the browser code and just do the request on the backend, but I don't see why I would have to do that.

Comment: It just says net::ERR_ABORTED 401

Comment: [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) means unauthorized. Is your credentials right?

Comment: Yeah, that is why I am confused. I use no credentials when I do the same request in postman. I only get it when requesting from the browser. The twitter documentation says you don't need credentials for this endpoint. you just need the oauth_token and the oauth_verifier from the step when the user approves access to the app.